# Geometry changes unexpectedly in TigerVNC

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

So something unexpected is going on: I can launch vnc with the configured (in /etc/vnc.conf) geometry, 3440x1440:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 32 x 32, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 32768 x 32768
VNC-0 connected 3440x1440+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3440x1440     60.00*+
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1360x768      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00
```

When I connect with RealVNC on Windows or Android, it gets the right high resolution. And it survives past disconnects and reconnects. However, if I connect with the vncclient command on my Linux laptop, it switches to the lower laptop resolution (1600x850 or something like that)...and even if I disconnect the session and reconnect and specify "vncclient -geometry 3440x1440 :0", it still goes with the lower laptop resolution, which, and this is the part that irks me, then somehow gets picked up by RealVNC next time I connect from it. The 3440x1440 mode disappears from the xrandr output as well. I have a script to add in the mode line and set it in xrandr as a workaround, so this isn't exactly high-impact to me, but I was wondering what was going on here. The logs don't give any indication of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a default setting in the TigerVNC client to set the remote server to local geometry. Press F8 and unselect the option. I don't see a command line option that overrides this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about TigerVNC, but in TightVNC there is **`-AcceptSetDesktopSize=off`** flag to lock the screen size to the original geometry.

For more details refer to [`man Xvnc`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/xvnc-1.html):

> ```
>        -AcceptSetDesktopSize
>               Accept  requests  to  resize the size of the desktop. Default is
>               on.
> ```